# number format changed while exporting from 2008 Crystal Report to excel .csv file

Tags: crystal-reports, export-to-csv

From 2008 Crystal Report view, the number format reads as 580015704027 in which is correct.

When exporting data from .rpt to .csv, that number format changes to 5.80016E+11.

How do I make it stick so that it will be exported correctly while on automation?

Thank you,
Holly

Comment: Excel is probably doing this as part of its cell formatting, not CR. Try opening the CSV in a text editor and see if it still displays that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

This solution works if you are using a database field with number format.

1. Right click on the filed go to `Format Field`.
2. Move to tab `Number`.
3. select last option `(1,123.0000)`

Now export to .CSV format.